# Adding Noodles to Soup

Tags: soup, noodles

If it takes 10 min to boil regular noodles if you drain the water after, give or take, how many minutes before the end of soup cooking should you add them in the pot considering they will keep on cooking in the hot soup after turning heat off so they are not overcooked?

Comment: Be careful with the whole concept of adding raw noodles to soup. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/can-i-add-uncooked-noodles-directly-to-soup?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Whether you choose to cook the noodles in the soup, or separately, once they are in the soup, you want to serve it immediately.  Either way, they will continue to absorb water and begin to grow mushy.  (this is why it is better to refrigerate or freeze soup without the noodles, and add them a la minute when you are heating it to serve later).

Because of this, if you do choose to cook the noodles directly in the broth, you would do so about the same amount of time before it is done, and then serve the soup immediately.

As long as the soup is above about 180 F / 82 C the noodles will be cooking at close to full speed, so if you are going to have hold time before service, you should count this in the cooking time.

Answer (score 2):

I just made a lovely turkey noodle soup and was looking for the answer and came across your question. Since these answers did not answer your question, I thought I’d answer with what I ended up doing.

I added shell noddles (recommended normal cooking time of 8 minutes) to the pretty much done soup. I continued cooking the soup on medium heat for another 15 minutes (tasting noodles as I went). I did think they had reached desired al dente after the 15 minutes, and removed from heat.

Comment: Oops typo… after the 15 minutes. They were too hard before then